# Java Swing - как динамически изменять поля фрейма?

Tags: java, swing

Имеется следующий функционал: при запуске программы открывается стартовый фрейм, в котором пользователю необходимо задать некоторые параметры. По нажатии кнопки в этом фрейме должен открыться некоторый текстовый файл с пометками, а также сбоку должно отобразиться дерево файловой системы. Из того, что я нашел, возможно создать новый фрейм с нужными вьюхами и полями, но он откроется в новом окне - это выглядит некрасиво и неправильно. Возможно ли средствами java swing изменять представление текущего окна, не открывая при этом новое?

P.S. вопрос не в том, как из текущего окна открыть текстовый файл. вопрос о том, как из текущего инициализированного фрейма перейти в новый так, чтобы это не выглядело как открытие нового окна в браузере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чистите все что есть во фрейме и добавляете по новой:

```
window.getContentPane().removeAll();
window.add(что-то там);
window.revalidate();
```

Comment: а это вообще нормальная практика или обычно фреймы так не чистят?

Comment: Вполне, не все элементы могут изменяться, их проще заменять новыми.